# android softkeyboard double tab spacebar to get period

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am building a softkeyboard based on the android softkeyboard sample code, now i want to write a period when the spacebar is pressed twice. is there anybody who has experience with this and is able to help me?

here is a link to the samplecode https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard?autodive=0%2F

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, except for looking at the example code?

Comment: @stealthjong no i dont know where to do so.